# How to setAutoPlayAnimations when initialize in Application?

Tags: fresco

I need to use gif support in my app, yet I have to enable autoplay by doing this in each view.

```
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                                    .setControllerListener(controllerListener)
                                    .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                                    .setUri()
                                    .build();
```

Consider there are so many views in my app need to display gif image, by doing this for every view just looks a little bit silly, so is there any way to set this config for all views when Fresco was initialized in application?